# editable listview in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I've got a list definition in `fxml`

```
<ListView fx:id="select_values" editable="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
```

My controller class for the list looks like this

```
public class ScriptGeneratorController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> select_values;
    private List<String> selectValueList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
    private ListProperty<String> selectValueListProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();

    @FXML
    private void handleQuestionGenerationAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(selectValueList); // list of [,,,,,]
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        select_values.itemsProperty().bind(selectValueListProperty);
        select_values.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
        select_values.setOnEditCommit(event -> select_values.getItems().set(event.getIndex(), event.getNewValue()));
        selectValueListProperty.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(selectValueList));
    }
}
```

But when I click on the button to do the action where I print list to console I get the list of empty strings (the same as initial). 
But on my form I clearly populate the values

[image]

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) says it

> Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it.

So your code creates a new list which is used as the backing list for the list view, and copies the content of `selectValueList` to that new list. When the user edits the content, the backing list is changed, but the changes are not propagated back to `selectValueList`.

You seem to have too many layers of data here. Probably all you need is

```
public class ScriptGeneratorController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> select_values;
    private ObservableList<String> selectValueList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("", "", "", "", "", "", "");

    @FXML
    private void handleQuestionGenerationAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(selectValueList); 
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        select_values.setItems(selectValueList);
        select_values.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
    }
}
```